# Firebase notifications not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated firebase push notifications in my app. Notifications are enabled in xcode. Certificates are also alright. But notifications are not showing in my app. Does anyone have any idea about that?

Here is my code:

```
[FIRApp configure];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
} else {
    // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= IPHONE_10_0
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
     requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     }
     ];

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
    //        [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
#endif
    }

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue may be caused if you don't put proper SDKs. Make sure you have these two:

'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/Messaging'

Comment: Ohh i was missing firebase/messaging in my project. It should show some error message. Thanks a lot.